# Use a foreign property in Symfony entity form type

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to find an easy way to use an entity form type, which uses the property from a joined table. I found a work around, but I hope this can be solved better than this.

In my situation, I want to show the translated text for my options in the selectbox. Unfortunately, the database is already there with it's translation tables, so I can't use the symfony country form type. So, for example, I have these tables:

```
        Country
+----+-------------+
| id | name        |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Netherlands |
|  2 | Germany     |
+----+-------------+


        CountryTranslation
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+
| id | language_id | country_id | text      |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |           1 |          1 | Nederland |
|  2 |           1 |          2 | Duitsland |
|  3 |           2 |          1 | ...       |
+----+-------------+------------+-----------+

        Flags
+----+------------+-----------------------------+
| id | country_id | img_url                     |
+----+------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 |          1 | http://flags.cdn.com/nl.gif |
+----+------------+-----------------------------+
```

Now in my CMT, I want the user to be able to manage the flags table. The CMT is multi-lingual, so it should show the countries in his own language. So in my formbuilder I would like to do something like this:

```php
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $flag = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (!$flag) {
        $form
            ->add('language', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MbDbLookupBundle:Country',
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->innerJoin('c.countryTranslations', 'ct', 'WITH', 'ct.languageId = :languageId')
                        ->leftJoin('MyCmtBundle:Flag', 'f', 'WITH', 'f.country = c')
                        ->where('f.country IS NULL')
                        ->setParameter('languageId', $this->lang)
                    },
                'property' => 'ct.text', // <--------- This will not work
                'label' => 'Language',
                'position' => array('before' => 'title'),
            ));
    }
}
```

### Things i've tried

- Use a 'choice' field with a [Data Transformer as explained here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html). This seemed ok at first, but I couldn't use this in my [dynamic form as explained here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data). This was because inside the addEventListener, I can use `$form->add`, but I cannot use `$form->add(form->create(...))` since the create function doesn't exist on that object.
- Create a custom form type. In my application I wanted the selectbox to be filled only with countries that weren't selected already. So I needed to join my "Flags" table as well, which is why I use the dynamic form. Therefore I cannot use the custom form type, because I need the query to be dynamic, based on the underlying data.

### My solution

In my Country entity I added the function `getNameTranslated($langId=null)`. When there is only one record in the array, it would return this. This way I could query the object with an inner join, making sure I already have the right translation inside the Country object. To make this function less filthy, one also has the option to fetch by the locale manually by using the parameter. So I came up with something like this:

```php
public function getNameTranslated($langId=null) {
    if (!isset($langId) && count($this->nameTranslations) > 1)
        throw new \Exception('No locale given '.count($this->nameTranslations));

    foreach($this->nameTranslations as $nameTranslation) {
        if (!isset($langId) || ($nameTranslation->getLanguageId() == $langId))
            return $nameTranslation;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now I can use `'property' => 'nameTranslated'` in my form builder, also inside the form event listener.

Somehow I still don't really like this solution. I would rather solve the problem inside my form, instead of inside the object.

What complicates things, I think, is that I am using this form event, and that I am joining my "Flags" table to rule out the languages already chosen. Otherwise I think the best options would be to go with the 'choice' field together with the Data Transformer. But I hope I am missing something and there is a better solution to use a foreign property.

Comment: I think your solution is fine. I would do exactly the same.

Comment: And here is my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33931892/2005817