# Symfony - How to pass related entity data to entity field's choices

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Good day everyone

I have Product entity that related to ProductType entity with many-to-one relation

I have the custom ProductsType field based on 'entity' field type:

```
class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'label' => 'oq.company.interest.label',
                'class' => 'OQReferenceBundle:Product',
                'required' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'empty_value' => 'oq.reference.interest.choose',
                'query_builder' => function ($repository) {
                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');

                    $qb->leftJoin('OQReferenceBundle:ProductType', 'pt', 'WITH', 'p.productType = pt.id')
                        ->addOrderBy('pt.name', 'ASC')
                        ->addOrderBy('p.name', 'ASC');

                    return $qb;
                },
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'oq_products_selector';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }
}
```

The 'oq_products_selector_widget' code:

```
{% block oq_products_selector_widget %}

    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>

        {% for id, child in form %}
            <div class="oro-clearfix">
                {{ form_widget(child) }}
                <label for="{{ child.vars.id }}">
                    {{ choices[id].data.name }} ({{ choices[id].data.productType.name }})
                </label>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

But when i try to render the form there is an exception:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable

As i understand the related entity data did not passed to choice data array and cannot be shown via `choices[id].data.productType.name`

How can i pass this data to choice?

Answer (score 0):

Hm, i solved that trouble.

I suppose that entity field type hydrates the objects for choice array without related entities. So i switched my custom field type parent to 'choice', then i received all the entities for choices with EntityManager and standart repository's `findAll` method and got data from all linked entities (ProductType) without any problems

**The code**

```
class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{

    /** @var EntityManager */
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addModelTransformer(new ProductsTransformer($this->em));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {

        $choices = array();
        $choicesAttrs = array();

        /** @var ProductRepository $repo */
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository("OQReferenceBundle:Product");
        if ($products = $repo->getProductsSortedByProductType()) {
            /** @var Product $product */
            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $choices[$product->getId()] = $product->getName();
                $choicesAttrs[$product->getName()] = array('data-product-type' => $product->getProductType()->getName());
            }
        }

        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'label' => 'oq.company.interest.label',
                'required' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'empty_value' => 'oq.reference.interest.choose',
                'choices' => $choices,
                'choice_attr' => $choicesAttrs,
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'oq_products_selector';
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }
}
```

As you can see i get all entities for choices and placed 'em in array. Then i get all the related entities names and placed them into another array. And passed this array to choices with `'choice_attr' => $choicesAttrs` parameter.

After that i have got an access to these additional data

```
{% block oq_products_selector_widget %}

    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        <div class="horizontal">

            {% set productType = '' %}

            {% for id, child in form %}
                <div class="oro-clearfix">

                    {% if productType != child.vars.attr['data-product-type'] %}
                        {% set productType = child.vars.attr['data-product-type'] %}
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 6px;">
                            <strong>{{ productType }}</strong>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}

                    {{ form_widget(child) }}
                    <label for="{{ child.vars.id }}">
                        {{ child.vars.label }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```